# Spring kafka deserialization issue

Tags: deserialization, spring-kafka

When I send a message that is not expected type,
The same log will be repeated.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:192) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1934) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1365) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition like-0 at offset 1. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:309) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:263) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.fetchRecords(AbstractFetch.java:340) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractFetch.collectFetch(AbstractFetch.java:306) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1235) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1186) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1159) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1649) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1624) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1313) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't deserialize data  from topic [like]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:588) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:300) ~[kafka-clients-3.6.1.jar:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'asd': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (byte[])"asd"; line: 1, column: 4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2477) ~[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:760) ~[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3699) ~[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2787) ~[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:908) ~[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:794) ~[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._initForReading(ObjectReader.java:357) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:2095) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1583) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:585) ~[spring-kafka-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

The official Spring documentation and other posts suggest "ErrorHandlingDeserializer"

[My consumer config]

```
@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group-01");

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);

        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class.getName());

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return props;
    }
```

(I also tried the yml config)

However, I am still not able to solve this problem.

Comment: It still looks like the `ErrorHnadlingDeserializer` is not configured properly. How do you provide it to the app? You need to pass the properties to the consumer factory. If you are using Boot, you an use `spring.kafka.consumer` properties. Please add more details on how you configure the deserializer? Maybe a small sample?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).